# Reading CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv

How to read the CSV file in Java?

I assume I need to use an InputStream.
How do I continue after the InputStream declaration?

```
InputStream file = item.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all lines with BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977308/read-all-lines-with-bufferedreader)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reading the CSV file, you can use the `BufferedReader` class:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("CSV file location"))
);
```

After that, use `StringTokenizer` to read each common separated values from the file, ex.:

```
if(reader.readLine()!=null) {
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(

    // this will read first line and separates values by (,) and stores them in tokens.
    (String) reader.readLine(), ",");

    tokens.nextToken(); // this method will read the tokens values on each call.
}
```

For example, the CSV file is having record of a employee, like:

```
ram,101
```

- The first time, the `tokens.nextToken()` call will return `ram`.
- The second time, the `tokens.nextToken()` call will return `101`.

Comment: This works considering that I am using the using a directory in my computer. However, I want is file upload but `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));` doesn't seem to work as I am getting an error in this line `List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);`

Answer (score 0):

For reading/manipulating csv in Java, you can check out [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) Library.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

"Commons CSV reads and writes files in variations of the Comma Separated Value (CSV) format."