# How to parse prettyprinted JSON with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, pretty-print

I'm connecting to some APIs. These calls return an already "prettyprinted" JSON instead of a one-line JSON.

Example:

```
[
  {
    "Field1.1": "Value1.1",
    "Field1.2": "value1.2",
    "Field1.3": "Value1.3"
  },
  {
    "Field2.1": "Value2.1",
    "Field2.2": "value2.2",
    "Field2.3": "Value2.3"
  }
]
```

When I try to parse a JSON like this with GSON it throws JsonSyntaxException.

Code example:

```
BufferedReader br = /*Extracting response from server*/
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(br.readLine())
```

Is there a way to parse JSON files formatted like this?

**EDIT**:

I tried using Gson directly:

```
BufferedReader jsonBuf = ....
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jobj = gson.fromJson(jsonBuf, JsonObject.class)
```

But `jobj` is NULL when the code terminates.

I also tried to parse the string contained into the BufferedReader into a single line string and then using JsonParser on that:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
BufferedReader jsonBuf = ....
JsonElement jEl = new JsonParser().parse(IOUtils.toString(jsonBuf).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

But the JsonElement I get in the end is a NULL pointer...

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: show the code that throws exception

Comment: @Deadpool done. Sorry, I forgot:D

Comment: You can read all lines as a single string: `br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());` (Requires Java 8. Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40412945) and not checked).

Comment: why don't you use `gson` directly instead of `JsonParser`?

Comment: And why do you pass a single line to the parser instead of passing the whole reader, from which Gson can read the whole document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedReader::nextLine` reads only one line. Either you read whole json from your reader to some `String` variable or you will use for example [`Gson::fromJson(Reader, Type)`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.io.Reader-java.lang.reflect.Type-) and pass reader directly to this method.

As your json looks like an array of json objects it can be deserialized to `List<Map<String,String>>` with usage of `TypeToken` :

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = ...
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Map<String,String>>>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Map<String,String>> newMap = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, type);
```

You could also use some custom object instead of `Map` depending on your needs.

Comment: If I use  Gson::fromJson(Reader, Type) do I have to specify the exact types and subtypes? Because the one I posted is just an example to show how the JSON I get is formatted, the structure can be more complex and I can't know it before parsing the JSON

Comment: You have to handle this json somehow. Either you read it to pure `String` (but this is not handy at all), you use some available type like `Map` or `List` of Strings or you create a custom POJO class for your json. If you do not know the structure of your json before parsing a `Map<String, String>` might be suitable.

Comment: I followed your suggestion eventually. I used a JsonArray instead of a custom type and it worked